# How do you simulate an IC when there are multiple variations of the IC?

Tags: ltspice, simulation

I am using the [LM2576HVT-15/NOPB](https://www.ti.com/product/LM2576HV#product-details) in one of my designs. I am trying to simulate the 15 volt version hence the "-15" in the part number. There is also a  3.3 V, 5 V, 12 V, and an adjustable output version for this same part number. I downloaded the spice model, but I don't understand how I get the 15 volt output version because there is only 1 spice model to download? How do I simulate the 15 volt output specifically and not one of the other versions?

I downloaded it and tried to simulate it as seen in the screenshot below, but it doesn't seem to be working.

[image]

Am I just simulating it wrong? Do I need  to change something in the .LIB file so it will be the 15V version?

Comment: Node references are meaningless in your picture

Comment: If you are lucky, you can edit the model in plain text and just change 15 to something else and get reasonably close for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"3.3 V, 5 V, 12 V, 15 V?" Usually, I can get the SPICE for the -adj version and add two resistors on the FB pin to make the version I want.  If you have the -adj version and use it with out resistors it will try to output 1.235V.
[image][DigiKey](https://www.digikey.com/en/htmldatasheets/production/99678/0/0/1/lm2576)

Answer (score 4):

The model LM2576HV_TRANS is for the 1.23V adjustable version only, so just add two resistors as per the datasheet to get the required output voltage.

eg. 10v out:

[image]